# How can I import updated data with MongoDB Compass?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

When i try to "add data" with my update json, it gets mad that there are duplicate IDs. It is trying to insert these documents, but i want it to update the old ones, using the IDs to match them. How do I do this within MongoDB Compass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a temporary collection
2. Use the add data to import your data into the temp collection
3. Open the mongod console, and run the following line

:

```
  db.TEMPCOLLECTIONNAME.aggregate([{$merge:{into:{coll:'TARGET COLLECTION NAME',db:'TARGET DB NAME'},on:'_id'}}])
```

Obviously replace the 3 names. You can leave out the DB property if the temp collection is in the same db as the target.

Comment: You don't actually need the `$match` stage. You can keep the `$merge` stage only.

Comment: thanks, removed it